# Strage Vue behaviour. V-if does not watch properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have a very strange problem. I have simple service and vue component. In template I have v-if which watches on service variable (if it is true - div should be displayed, should not otherwise). It works when I define variable with assigned boolean value but it does not when variable is undefined. My method isOpened() evaluates it to boolean anyway so I do not understand why this code does not work as it should. Maybe code below will explain this issue better:

```
<template>
    <div id="communicate" v-if="service.isOpened()">
        This should display if 'f' property in service is true
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

class OtherService {
    private f:boolean = false; //works, div is displayed with this line uncommented
    //private f:boolean; // f is undefined - does not work with this line uncommented

    public info(foo:string) { this.f = true; }
    public isOpened() { return (this.f === true) } //f is evaluated to bool anyway so it should not be any difference 
}
export default {
    name: 'component',
    data: function() {
        return {
            service: new OtherService()
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        console.log(this.service.isOpened()) //prints always false - ok
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.service.info('setting f to true') // f is set to true
            console.log(this.service.isOpened()) // prints true, div should display.
        }, 2000)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the way TypeScript transpiles class properties without values.

Consider two classes:

```
class ClassA {
    private myProperty: boolean;
}

class ClassB {
    private myProperty: boolean = false;
}
```

In ClassA we define a property which TypeScript knows about. In ClassB we define a property which TypeScript knows about AND assigns a value to.

In ES5 these transpile to the following:

```
var ClassA = (function () {
    function ClassA() {
    }
    return ClassA;
}());

var ClassB = (function () {
    function ClassB() {
        this.myProperty = false;
    }
    return ClassB;
}());
```

It is easy to see that this property is actually only created once the value is assigned. And without it, Vue cannot know that this property exists.

If you take a look at the guide at [vuejs.org](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) there is a section about reactivity.

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive.